# How can I form MySQL query to return required rows based on these 4 related tables?

Tags: mysql

I have a site where I am administering guitar courses. As part of a `course`, there are various content types, such as `assignment`, `quiz`, discussion `topic`.

A `course` itself, as well as content such as `assignment`, `topic`, and `quiz` are stored in same table. Here is example:

```
-- schema
CREATE TABLE posts (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    post_type VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    post_title VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    post_parent INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
;

-- data
INSERT INTO posts
    (id, post_type, post_title, post_parent)
VALUES
    (1, 'course', 'Course1', 0),
    (2, 'course-topic', 'An Assignment for Course1', 0),
    (3, 'quiz', 'A Quiz for Course1', 0),
    (4, 'quiz', 'Another Quiz for Course1', 0),
    (5, 'forum', 'Required Discussions', 0),
    (6, 'topic', 'Topic for Course1 Forum', 5),
    (7, 'course-topic', 'Another Assignment for Course1', 0),
    (8, 'topic', 'Another Topic for Course1 Forum', 5),
    (9, 'course', 'Course2', 0),
    (10, 'quiz', 'A Quiz for Course2', 0),
    (11, 'quiz', 'Another Quiz for Course2', 0),
    (12, 'course-topic', 'An Assignment for Course2', 0),
    (13, 'forum', 'Required Discussions', 0),
    (14, 'topic', 'Topic for Course2 Forum', 13),
    (15, 'course-topic', 'Another Assignment for Course2', 0),
    (16, 'topic', 'Another Topic for Course2 Forum', 13),
    (17, 'other', 'Some Other Post', 0),
    (18, 'forum', 'Some Other Forum', 0),
    (19, 'topic', 'Topic for Other Forum', 18)
;
```

**A `quiz` is its own content type. So in Posts Table it has `post_type = quiz`.**

**A required discussion has `post_type = topic`, `post_parent = forum_id`, where title of forum is 'Required Discussions' and it is a post item with `post_type = forum`**

**An `assignment` on the other hand is a post of type `post_type=course-topic`, and with `taxonomy` 'Assignment'.**

So here are additional tables that set up an `assignment` taxonomy:

```
-- schema
CREATE TABLE taxonomy (
    taxonomy_id INT NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(taxonomy_id)
)
;

-- data
INSERT INTO taxonomy
    (taxonomy_id, description)
VALUES
    (1, 'Some Category'),
    (2, 'Assignments'),
    (3, 'Some Other Category')
;

-- schema
CREATE TABLE taxonomy_relations (
    post_id INT NOT NULL,
    taxonomy_id VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(post_id)
)
;

-- data
INSERT INTO taxonomy_relations
    (post_id, taxonomy_id)
VALUES
    (2, 2),
    (7, 2),
    (12, 2),
    (15, 2)
;
```

Now, to tie everything to a given `course`, there is a meta table with a meta_key `related_course` that is set for all content types.

```
-- schema
CREATE TABLE meta (
    meta_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    post_id INT NOT NULL,
    meta_key VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    meta_value VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(meta_id)
)
;

-- data
INSERT INTO meta
    (meta_id, post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'some_key', 'some val'),
    (2, 1, 'some_otherkey', 'some other val'),
    (3, 2, 'another_key', 'and a value'),
    (4, 2, 'related_course', '1'),
    (5, 3, 'related_course', '1'),
    (6, 4, 'related_course', '1'),
    (7, 5, 'related_course', '1'),
    (8, 6, 'related_course', '1'),
    (9, 7, 'related_course', '1'),
    (10, 8, 'related_course', '1'),
    (11, 10, 'related_course', '9'),
    (12, 11, 'related_course', '9'),
    (13, 12, 'related_course', '9'),
    (14, 13, 'related_course', '9'),
    (15, 14, 'related_course', '9'),
    (16, 15, 'related_course', '9'),
    (17, 16, 'related_course', '9'),
    (18, 19, 'related_course', '1'),
;
```

Notice in above, that discussion topic with id 19 from posts table has a `related_course` meta value, but that it is not one of my defined ***required tasks***. It is just some topic reply in some other forum for the course. The point being, there can be a lot of interrelated content here, but required tasks are as I defined above: 1) quizzes, 2) posts of type `course-topic` who have Assignment taxonomy, and 3) posts of type `topic` whose parent forum is titled 'Required Discussions'.

Lastly, when a user completes some task (assignment, quiz, or topic reply), I store info in a `taskstatus` table:

```
-- schema
CREATE TABLE taskstatus (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    task_id INT NOT NULL,
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    passed INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
;

-- data
INSERT INTO taskstatus
    (id, task_id, user_id, passed)
VALUES
    (1, 2, 53, 1),
    (2, 4, 53, 0),
    (3, 6, 53, 1)
;
```

Then to track completion of required tasks I have a `taskstatus` table.

```
-- schema
CREATE TABLE taskstatus (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    task_id INT NOT NULL,
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    passed INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
;

-- data
INSERT INTO taskstatus
    (id, task_id, user_id, passed)
VALUES
    (1, 6, 53, 1),
    (2, 4, 53, 0),
    (3, 2, 53, 1),
    (4, 11, 53, 1),
    (5, 2, 24, 1),
    (6, 4, 24, 1),
    (7, 6, 24, 0)
;
```

**Here is sqlfiddle:**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6430ff/4

This `taskstatus` table shows that user 53 completed the Assignment, one Quiz (though didn't pass), and Discussion Topic from the course with id 1.  It also shows user 53 completed a Quiz from another course (with id 9 in posts table). This table gets populated only on completion of a task.

The table also shows status for user 24.

Now, finally, what I am after: I am trying to figure out if there is a single query that can get me task status for a given user and given course across all required task types - Assignments, Quizzes, Discussions.

**In current example if targeting user_id 53 and course_id 1, the result should be**

```
desired results:
--------------------------------------------
task_id   passed
2         1
3         NULL
4         0         
6         1
7         NULL
8         NULL
```

I suspect it will involve a bit of INNER JOINS, maybe a LEFT or RIGHT OUTER JOIN at some point to ensure I get that NULL row for a task that has no status in the `taskstatus` table.

But this is way beyond anything I have attempted in MySQL and just not sure how to tie all this together.

To get started, here are required quizzes and forum topics:

```
-- get quizzes and forum topics
SELECT tasks.id, tasks.post_type  FROM posts as tasks
INNER JOIN meta as pm ON pm.post_id = tasks.ID
LEFT JOIN posts as forums ON forums.id = tasks.post_parent
WHERE (pm.meta_key = 'related_course') 
  AND (pm.meta_value=1) 
  AND (tasks.post_type='quiz' OR (tasks.post_type='topic') AND (forums.post_title='Required Discussions'));
  
-- how to add assignments?
```

Now I have to figure out

1. How to add assignments to the result rows
2. Finally, how to show the task status as shown above in `desired results`.

### Edit

This seems to work:

```
SELECT tasks.id, tasks.post_type, tstatus.passed FROM posts as tasks
LEFT JOIN meta as pm ON pm.post_id = tasks.ID
LEFT JOIN posts as forums ON forums.id = tasks.post_parent
LEFT JOIN taxonomy_relations AS taxrel ON taxrel.post_id = tasks.id
LEFT JOIN taxonomy AS tax ON taxrel.taxonomy_id = tax.taxonomy_id
LEFT JOIN taskstatus as tstatus ON tstatus.task_id = tasks.id AND tstatus.user_id=53
WHERE (pm.meta_key = 'related_course') 
  AND (pm.meta_value=1) 
  AND ((tasks.post_type='quiz') OR ((tasks.post_type='course-topic') AND (tax.description='Assignments')) OR ((tasks.post_type='topic') AND (forums.post_title='Required Discussions')) )
```

This produces

```
id  post_type   passed
2   course-topic    1
4   quiz            0
6   topic           1
3   quiz         (null)
7   course-topic (null)
8   topic        (null)
```

But I got this just by experimenting. I really have no idea how to really do this, and I noticed I get same results even by varying the JOIN types, which has me worried that some small detail can break this query.

How can I fine tune this?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: First you start with what is the desired result, and the you look how you kan get those columns in yourr From Clause, that is the basiscs for all query. But i can't for example see what where you get you task_id, it appears quit at the end but this seems to the one of the result fields, also all yout relations don't seem to lead to task_id. very confusing

Comment: task_id relates to one of the post types 'topic', 'quiz', or 'course-topic', and in case of 'course-topic' only where taxonomy is as described in the post. So for a given user, and given course id, there might be 10 tasks, and for that user the task status table might have 5 entries. But end result should be 10 rows, and for cases where the task id is not in the status table, then there would be NULL.

Comment: Please chop down this code down to some correct code with its specification extended by wrong code & its unmet specification. **When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.** Explain how you are then stuck. [mre] This is not minimal. See my comments on your later related post. PS [Is there any rule of thumb to construct SQL query from a human-readable description?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33952141/3404097) PS Please clarify via edits, not comments.